# El lector de datos devuelto por el proveedor de datos de almacenamiento no tiene bastantes columnas para la consulta solicitada

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Saludos.

En Entity Framework, al intentar realizar un insert, me manda el siguiente mensaje:

> El lector de datos devuelto por el proveedor de datos de almacenamiento no tiene bastantes columnas para la consulta solicitada.

Sin embargo el registro sí se guarda. Esto sucede sólo algunas veces, no siempre. No he encontrado alguna respuesta que me sirva en Internet.

¿Podrían ayudarme a explicarme de qué va este error? Y si manda error, ¿por qué se está guardando el registro?

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Por favor incluye el stack trace (pila de llamadas) que acompaña a tu error. Y lo ideal es que incluyas un [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

No se si aún te servirá o si se ajustará a tu caso, pero a mi me estaba pasando y me estaba volviendo loco y al final resulto que una tabla que modificaba en el procedimiento tenía un trigger que era el que tenía problemas realmente. Si ese es el caso revísalo. El problema venía de un trigger preparado para un cambio de un solo registro pero se estaban eliminando varios (al comparar con INSERT o DELETE es necesario cambiar los "=" por "IN").

Espero que te ayude, o ayude a otros con el mismo caso  ;)

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso, el problema era que estaba intentando guardar un Guid como Guid.Empty en lugar de null.
Como era un Foreign Key y no había ninguna clave que fuera igual a Guid.Empty Entity Framework me daba ese error.
Espero te sirva.